# getClassloader returns null instead of the bootstrap classloader

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

As it is known, classes from rt.jar library are loaded via Bootstrap Classloader.
java.lang is a part of rt.jar library.

However, this sample

```
System.out.println(ArrayList.class.getClassLoader());
```

prints `null` instead of something like `BootstrapClassLoader`.

Also, I know that BootstrapClassLoader is not written in Java.
Can it be the reason?
And how can I make sure that the class is loaded by BootstrapCL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Class#getClassLoader
```

The documentation explicitly warns you about this case.

> Returns the class loader for the class.
>  Some implementations **may use
>   null to represent the bootstrap class loader**.

Remember to always give a look at the associated *JavaDoc*. That is valid for everything and it might be a lifesaver sometimes.